# What options are there for good Low DC Voltage, High Amperage Alligator Clip connections?

Tags: connector, terminal

I have a 12V DC, 20A compressor for my offroad vehicle to inflate its tyres after driving on the beach. I also have high current jumper leads with large alligator clips at each end for starting cars with a flat battery. The compressor has flying leads with bare copper ends. What options are there for *a solid connection* (without the risk of a short circuit) if I want to power my compressor from the car battery using the jumper leads?

Here is a diagram of the setup:
[image]

One option is some high-current jumper terminals, but these are quite costly.
[image]

I could possibly make my own out of a block of wood, and two bolts.

Does anyone have any other ideas or advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your cigarette lighter fuse. It might be 20A-rated, in which case, that is an appropriate connection.

If that's not an option, any connector of the kind you'd find on starter cables will do; you can buy those with a screw terminal to attach your compressors' cables.

Comment: Cigarette lighter fuses are normally 10A.

Comment: @vini_i I've really seen them in any rating between 10 and 25 A.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, 20A isn't high-ampere in car electrics. The starter has 250A. My advice would be to neither use starter crocodile clips nor the terminal blocks. They are both suitable for 300A minimum, that's 15 times overkill for your application.

Pick a connector from a car parts store which is rated 25A and you should be all right.

Comment: @JimmyB: No. Please check your jump-start cables. You can put 10A on 1mm² cross section continously. Typical jump-start cables have >20mm² cross-section and dramatically large alligator clips which easily take 300A.

Comment: I don't discuss this further. Please look into the switchbox of your car and see the tiny 30A fuses there.

Comment: @JimmyB then you've got terribly jumper cables.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, you're right. They *are* spec'd for 100's of amps. I mixed up the specs and the current I measured hastily last time when jump starting. Please ignore my comments, I'll delete them in a moment.

Comment: But... I think I'll have to do a little experiment and measure the car-to-car resistance.

Comment: @JimmyB you might need to come up with a good way to do that – it's kind of hard to measure resistance accurately if it involves not only the contacts you want to measure, but also the measurement device contacts. Point here also being that the 40A a medium-sized starter might pull actually might behave a bit differently with respect to the conductor interfaces than the microamps your resistance meter will put through.

Answer (score 0):

20A compressor probably has motor winding resistance yielding 100~200A peak currents or < 0.1 Ohm DCR. To make efficient connections for low V drop choose connector with 1% DCR or 1 MilliOhm contacts. Higher is OK but >10 MilliOhm starts to affect compressor.

- Jumper cable clips work sometimes but surface oxidation and high spring force are needed with sharp edges to jump start car with similar 200A~800A currents especially in cold weather requires experience and good jumper cables.
- This is what I would consider using.
  (Welder waterproof connectors)  ***CDN$ 5.65***

110 x 22mm/4.33 x 0.87"(L x Dia)

[image]

"BQLZR IP68 Grade 2Pin Waterproof Plug Socket Electric Cable Wire Connector M19 Welding Type "

Comment: I'd say this is certainly an excellent choice, but also pretty much overkill. The car compressors I've seen came with cheap-o battery clamps and worked excellently. You might be overengineering this :)

Comment: cheapo clamps works as long as battery terminals that are not salt-water copper sulphate corroded, but quick disconnect cheapo welder cables that are water proof ought to work well for frequent beach runs on deflated tires followed by restoring "tyre" pressure. The key is acknowledging motor peak currents can be up to 5~10x average current on compressor pumps

Comment: While I'd vote for waterproof connectors in cars, too, it doesn't make sense to use a two-pin waterproof connector when you have two cables going in there. The waterproof is gone then. I would use two pairs of waterproof single-wire connectors and to make them safe against swapping, use plug+pin on one side and pin+plug of the other side, too.

Comment: again, I **like** the solution you're proposing! However, you'd also have to acknowledge the fact that a car compressor motor will be designed to start even if current gets limited by bad contact; I agree, scratching your clamp on the battery terminal until you get reasonable contact is inconvenient, so again: go, welder contacts!

Comment: Yes but user should keep in mind if voltage drops, compressor motor slows down and  while motor current oscillates from (est) 1 to 35A from intake to compression cycle averaging <20A it  can blow 20A fuse as reported by many users on web. So fuse ratings must be used with caution

Comment: Any 1/4" bolt with spade lugs and nut will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Look at marine (or fishing?) supply stores for trolling motor battery connectors.  They should be rated for higher currents than your compressor requires.